# Efficiency difference between an if-statement and mod(SIZE)

Tags: c, performance, if-statement, processing-efficiency

Studying I found the use of the `(i+1)mod(SIZE)` to perform a cycle in an array of elements.
So I wondered if this method was more efficient than an if-statement...

---

For example:

```
#define SIZE 15

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int items[SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; items[0] < 5; i = (i + 1) % SIZE) items[i] += 1;

    return 0;
}
```

It is more efficient than(?):

```
#define SIZE 15

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int items[SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; items[0] < 5; i++) {
        if(i == SIZE) i = 0;
        items[i] += 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Thanks for the answers and your time.

Comment: Profile it. Totally depends on your target architecture/compiler. In general reducing number of branches is a good thing, but we don't know how modulus will be implemented. Also we don't know how smart the compiler is to figure it out.

Comment: Modulo is expensive.  Branching is also expensive.  Benefit of branching in a loop, though, is you'll frequently be taking the same branch over and over which will allow the CPU to predict which branch will be taken and reduce the cost of the branch as it won't need to flush the pipeline when it guesses correctly.  Only way to know for sure which is better is to profile.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How does one profile? `gcc -pg -g3` combined with `gprof` doesn't work, and `prof` doesn't, either.

Comment: @JL2210 Run a zillion of loops and time them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are only asking about `mod` vs `branch`, there are probably more like five cases depending on the actual implementation of the `mod` and branch:

### Modulus-based

#### Power-of-two

If the value of `SIZE` is known to the compiler and is a power of 2, the `mod` will compile into a single `and` [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/7lWIpj) and will be very efficient in performance and code size. The `and` is still part of the loop increment dependency chain though, putting a [speed limit](https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html#carried-dependency-chains) on the performance of 2 cycles per iteration unless the compiler is clever enough to unroll it and keep the `and` out of the carried chain (gcc and clang weren't).

#### Known, not power-of-two

On the other hand, if the value of `SIZE` is known but not a power of two, then you are likely to get a multiplication-based implementation of the fixed modulus value, [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/gL7cW2). This generally takes something like 4-6 instructions, which end up part of the dependency chain. So this will limit your performance to something like 1 iteration every 5-8 cycles, depending exactly on the latency of the dependency chain.

#### Unknown

In your example `SIZE` is a known constant, but in the more general case where it is not known at compile time you will get an division instruction on platforms that support it. Something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/grcr1R).

That is good for code size, since it's a single instruction, but probably disastrous for performance because now you have a slow division instruction as part of the carried dependency for the loop. Depending on your hardware and the type of the `SIZE` variable, you are looking at 20-100 cycles per iteration.

### Branch-based

You put a branch in your code, but jump compiler made decide to implement that as  a conditional jump or as a conditional move. At `-O2`, [gcc decides on a jump and clang on a conditional move](https://godbolt.org/z/B2ChT_).

#### Conditional Jump

This is the direct interpretation of your code: use a conditional branch to implement the `i == SIZE` condition.

It has the advantage of making the condition a control dependency, not a data dependency, so your loop will mostly run at full speed when the branch is not taken.

However, performance could be seriously impacted if the branch mispredicts often. That depends heavily on the value of `SIZE` and on your hardware. Modern Intel should be able to predict nested loops like this up to 20-something iterations, but beyond that it will mispredict once every time the inner loop is exited. Of course, is `SIZE` is very large then the single mispredict won't matter much anyways, so the worst case is `SIZE` just large enough to mispredict.

#### Conditional Move

clang uses a conditional move to update `i`. This is a reasonable option, but it does mean a carried data flow dependency of 3-4 cycles.

---

<sup>1</sup> Either *actually* a constant like your example or effectively a constant due to inlining and constant propagation.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the assembly online (i. e. [here](https://godbolt.org/)). The result depends on the architecture and the optimization, but without optimization and for x64 with GCC, you get this code (as a simple example).

Example 1:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-68], edi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-80], rsi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
.L3:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-64]
        cmp     eax, 4
        jg      .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-64+rax*4]
        lea     edx, [rax+1]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-64+rax*4], edx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        add     eax, 1
        movsx   rdx, eax
        imul    rdx, rdx, -2004318071
        shr     rdx, 32
        add     edx, eax
        mov     ecx, edx
        sar     ecx, 3
        cdq
        sub     ecx, edx
        mov     edx, ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edx
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        mov     edx, ecx
        sal     edx, 4
        sub     edx, ecx
        sub     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Example 2:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-68], edi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-80], rsi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
.L4:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-64]
        cmp     eax, 4
        jg      .L2
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 15
        jne     .L3
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
.L3:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-64+rax*4]
        lea     edx, [rax+1]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-64+rax*4], edx
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jmp     .L4
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

You see, that for the specific case with x86, the solution without modulo is much shorter.

Comment: "[W]ithout optimization" is not useful when the point is to try to get an algorithm to run as fast as possible.

Comment: Size of the code is not a measure of performance.. Also any production code *should* be compiled with optimizations.

Comment: You can add optimization options at the website. My two examples are only simple examples to show the difference in one specific case because I don´t know which architecture the TE wants to use.
You have all grades of freedom if you use the compiler explorer. You can play around and find the optimal solution for your platform.

Comment: I have an AMD x64 CPU (gcc version 8.3.0). But from what I understand there is no real way to know if one solution is faster than the other.
If I don't test them both ...

Comment: Some applications need a constant run time instead of a short run time, then modulo would be my first choice. But as others said you need to look into the generated assembly code to see what the compiler did.